# main.DEBUG: Request validation failed for action ... Invalid request received at Account/CreatePost.php:327 on loop error in debug log

Tags: magento2, customer, debug, action, request

Hey There i have been facing a serious issue in my magento 2.3.7.
in my debug.log this error is constantly hitting n filling it in seconds

```
Request validation failed for action "Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost\Interceptor" {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\InvalidRequestException(code: 0): Invalid request received at /home/h1/public_html/vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/CreatePost.php:327)"} []
```

i have no idea why this is causing and which module is conflicting but because of this my site is going slow
please suggest me something to resolve this

THanks in Advance :)

Comment: Have you find any solution to it?

Comment: Not yet .......................

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your local virtual host name. Name should be in 2 parts, separated by a Dot(.) You may be running it like http://localhost/ or http://example/ . Somebody in stack overflow told me that it should be split by Dot. Dot is necessary otherwise that problem will occur. Than i changed my local virtual host name to http://localhost.co/ OR http://example.ty/ and the issue get fixed.